# LINQ JOIN + GROUP BY + SUM

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, sum, aggregate

I have two LINQ statements that I would like to make into one, but for the life of me I can't get it to work.

I can't get the grouping to work in the first statement.
It complains that the `TotalBuy` and `TotalSell` properties aren't there, although doesn't complain about `AmountTC` and `AmountAUD`.

This should be simple. Any thoughts?

```
var itineraryItems =
    from ii in this.ItineraryItemRecords
    join t in this.TransactionRecords on ii.OperatorID equals t.
    TransactionActor.OperatorID into g select new {
    OperatorID = ii.OperatorID, TotalBuy = g.Sum(i = >ii.TotalBuy)
        , TotalSell = g.Sum(i = >ii.TotalSell)
        , PaidTC = (0 - (g.Sum(t = >t.AmountTC)))
        , PaidAUD = (0 - (g.Sum(t = >t.AmountAUD)))
};

var itineraryItemz =
    from i in itineraryItems group i by i.OperatorID into g select new {
    OperatorID = g.Key, TotalBuy = g.Sum(i = >i.TotalBuy)
        , TotalSell = g.Sum(i = >i.TotalSell)
        , PaidTC = (0 - (g.Sum(i = >i.PaidTC)))
        , PaidAUD = (0 - (g.Sum(i = >i.PaidAUD)))
};
```

As a side note, `ItineraryItemRecords` and `TransactionRecords` are Collections of classes handled by `SubSonic`.

This really should be simple, so any help would be appreciated.

Regards,
John

Comment: @JohnBob - I re-tagged your question with a c# tag so that it may get more notice as no one has responded yet.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A minor mistake, corrected:

```
var itineraryItems = from ii in this.ItineraryItemRecords 
   join t in this.TransactionRecords on ii.OperatorID equals t.TransactionActor.OperatorID 
   into g 
   select new 
   { 
       OperatorID = ii.OperatorID 
       //, TotalBuy = g.Sum(i => ii.TotalBuy) 
       , TotalBuy = g.Sum(i => i.TotalBuy) 
       //, TotalSell = g.Sum(i => ii.TotalSell) 
       , TotalSell = g.Sum(i => i.TotalSell) 
       , PaidTC = (0 - (g.Sum(t => t.AmountTC))) 
       , PaidAUD = (0 - (g.Sum(t => t.AmountAUD))) 
   };
```

I recommend against re-using identifiers - will help avoid these mistakes in the future.

Comment: Hey, 

I appreciate the help here from you two, thanks for the comment.
Unfortunately, I've thrown this code in and it's not working.


It complains about TotalBuy and TotalSell.
"Cannot resolve symbol TotalBuy"
'ResSystem.Library.Objects.Transaction' does not contain a definition for 'TotalBuy' and no extension method 'TotalBuy' accepting a first argument of type 'ResSystem.Library.Objects.Transaction' could be found


What's wrong with my syntax here?

Comment: Never mind.
I ended up splitting this into three separate queries.
Two group by queries, and then one joining these two group by queries.